# ASP.NET/C# - Detect File Size from Other Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to find the file size of a file on a server. The following code I got from [this guy](http://www.thejackol.com/2005/06/11/aspnet-get-file-size/) accomplishes that for your own server:

```
string MyFile = "~/photos/mymug.gif";

FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(MyFile));
long FileInBytes = finfo.Length;
long FileInKB = finfo.Length / 1024;

Response.Write("File Size: " + FileInBytes.ToString() + 
  " bytes (" + FileInKB.ToString() + " KB)");
```

It works. However, I want to find the filesize of, for example:

```
string MyFile = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif";

FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(MyFile);
```

Then I get a pesky error saying `URI formats are not supported.`

How can I find the file size of Google's logo with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `WebRequest` class to issue an HTTP request to the server and read the `Content-Length` header (you could probably use HTTP `HEAD` method to accomplish it). However, not all Web servers respond with a `Content-Length` header. In those cases, you have to receive all data to get the size.

Comment: I tried your method, but got the whole file as a `WebRequest` response

Comment: @Desolator: Are you sure the web server was sane?

Comment: I think the sever works probably. This method is working just fine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11697647/586399

Comment: @Desolator that method does not only receive headers. It'll receive as many packets as you can receive before you shut down the connection, so it's quite different from the ideal HEAD request. My guess would be that the server has not implemented the HEAD method correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To get this value you would have to first download the file locally, then you can use the standard methods to get its size.

Comment: Dang. That's the ONLY way to do it?

Comment: Mehrdad offered the only other alternative that I know of, but as he mentioned it is a bit sketchy in support

Comment: so if the file was 1GB do you expect him to download that?

Comment: Sadly, it is the only really way to go, if Mehrdad's answer doesn't work.