# Getting a header/filesize in .NET

Tags: .net, download, webclient

I have a link to two files. They may be the same file, but they may not be the same URL. I want to figure out if they are the same by checking the content-length before doing a full download. What's the best way to do this?

Currently I am using webbrowser control to load the page and extract data and then using `WebClient.Download` to get the file. Is there a way I can use WebClient to check the filesize before downloading the entire file?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357190/asp-net-c-detect-file-size-from-other-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an excellent article, *[Get file length over HTTP before you download it](http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2010/08/get-file-length-over-http-before-you.html)*, which provides a way that works very well for me:

```
    static public long GetFileSize(string url)
    {
        using (WebClient obj = new WebClient())
        using (Stream s = obj.OpenRead(url))
            return long.Parse(obj.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"].ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Equality of lengths does not mean that files are identical. However, if you're sure that this is enough to assert equality, you can issue a `HttpWebRequest` with `Method` set to `HEAD`: this will only download file headers, including `content-length`.

Comment: assuming that the content-length header gets set which may vary depending on the web server and whether any server side code is involved in the downloading

Comment: HEAD requests are SUPPOSED to be processed the same as normal, then have the body discarded... But you're right, some systems are probably lazy.